# Rewrite nested SELECT by using JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, join, nested

Does it make any sense to rewrite this query using JOIN for MySQL 5.6+ in order to increase performance? If so, how?

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab WHERE 
col2 > 1234 
AND col2 < 9876 
AND col3 IN (1,2,3,4) 
AND col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM tab 
             WHERE col3 IN (1,2,3,4) 
                 AND col4 = 10 
             GROUP BY col1 
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col3) = 4)
```

Comment: Since you are using GROUP BY and HAVING in the inner select, it is likely that this query can't be written with a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions I can think of.

Firstly you do a join to the sub query rather than using an IN clause

```
SELECT tab.col1, 
        tab.col2, 
        tab.col3 
FROM tab 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT col1 
    FROM tab 
    WHERE col3 IN (1,2,3,4) 
    AND col4 = 10 
    GROUP BY col1 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col3) = 4
) sub0
ON tab.col1 = sub0.col1
WHERE col2 > 1234 
AND col2 < 9876 
AND col3 IN (1,2,3,4) 
AND col1 IN
```

Depending on the number of matches, etc this might be more efficient.

Possibly more efficient, but less flexible would be to do a join back to the table for each specific value of col3 with a col4 of 10 that you require. If any are missing then the join results in the row being excluded. Down side is that you will need a DISTINCT on the SELECT to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab0.col1, 
        tab0.col2, 
        tab0.col3 
FROM tab AS tab0
INNER JOIN tab AS tab1 ON tab0.col1 = tab1.col1 AND tab1.col3 = 1 AND tab1.col4 = 10
INNER JOIN tab AS tab2 ON tab0.col1 = tab2.col1 AND tab2.col3 = 2 AND tab2.col4 = 10
INNER JOIN tab AS tab3 ON tab0.col1 = tab3.col1 AND tab3.col3 = 3 AND tab3.col4 = 10
INNER JOIN tab AS tab4 ON tab0.col1 = tab4.col1 AND tab4.col3 = 4 AND tab4.col4 = 10
WHERE tab0.col2 > 1234 
AND tab0.col2 < 9876 
AND tab0.col3 IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: @pedmillon - not tested it but it should do as an equivalent of your original query